# How to save an optional value to a 1:1 relationship in Amplify DataStore

Tags: swift, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Background to the **models**: A shared **car** is being used in a **city** for **trips** A trip can be outward or a return.

I am saving a car model with several fields. One field is the cityID of Type Relationship Source in Amplify UI(The city has got a one to many car relationship). Further the car has two fields with 1:1 relationships to a trip model. A trip can be a outward or a return trip. But in some cases a car is only used for an outward drive so there is no return trip or the return will be in a time in the future.

| Relationship name | Related to | Cardinality | is required |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Outward | Trip | 1:1 one Car to one Trip | x |
| Return | Trip | 1:1 one Car to one Trip |  |

When there is no return trip (the parameter Outward of the car is: nil), the Error message goes:

> Could not save car item to DataStore: DataStoreError: The data
> couldn’t be read because it is missing. Recovery suggestion: The data
> couldn’t be read because it is missing. Caused by:
> valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
> [CodingKeys(stringValue: "elements", intValue: nil),
> _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "Return", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue:
> nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null
> instead.", underlyingError: nil))

When there is no Return trip the car model cannot save the return trips id.

What is the best solution for this or is there a workaround except saving a dummy return trip every time?

Current code:

```
// Create car item
let carItem = Car(id: UUID().uuidString,
                            ...
                            ...
                            Outward: oTripItem!,
                            Return: rTripItem,
                            sessionID: car.belongsToCityID!)
            
            // Store car in DB
            Amplify.DataStore.save(carItem) { result in
                switch(result) {
                case .success(let savedItem):
                    print("Saved car item: \(savedItem.id)")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Could not save car item to DataStore: \(error)")
                }
            }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm facing the same problem. I have a 1:1 relationship between User and Location (a user may optionally have a Location) and I get the same error message.